# spinnaker /halyard : Unable to communicate with the Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, spinnaker

I am trying to deploy spinnaker on multi node . I have 2 VMs : the first with halyard and kubectl the second contain the kubernetes master api.
 my kubectl is well configured and able to communicate with the remote kubernetes api,

the "kubectl get namespaces " works

```
kubectl get namespaces
NAME          STATUS    AGE
default       Active    16d
kube-public   Active    16d
kube-system   Active    16d
```

but when I run this cmd

```
hal config provider -d kubernetes account add spin-kubernetes --docker-registries myregistry 
 I get this error
 Add the spin-kubernetes account
  Failure
Problems in default.provider.kubernetes.spin-kubernetes:
- WARNING You have not specified a Kubernetes context in your
  halconfig, Spinnaker will use "default-system" instead.
? We recommend explicitly setting a context in your halconfig, to
  ensure changes to your kubeconfig won't break your deployment.
? Options include:
  - default-system

! ERROR Unable to communicate with your Kubernetes cluster:
  Operation: [list]  for kind: [Namespace]  with name: [null]  in namespace:
  [null]  failed..
? Unable to authenticate with your Kubernetes cluster. Try using
  kubectl to verify your credentials.

- Failed to add account spin-kubernetes for provider
  kubernetes.
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the cluster in your halconfig?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message there seem to be two approaches to this, set your halconfig to talk to the default-system context, so it could communicate with your cluster or the other way around, that is configure your context.

Try this:

```
kubectl config view
```

I suppose you'll see the context and current context over there to be default-system, try changing those.
For more help do

```
kubectl config --help
```

I guess you're looking for the set-context option.
Hope that helps.

Comment: no , I specified the configuration to use , and I can access with kubectl to the remote cluster , but it seems that halyard are using another way to test the acces to the kubernetes cluster. i don't know if there is another file that i need to configure

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in your halconfig as mentioned by @Naim Salameh.

Another way is to try setting your K8S cluster info in your default Kubernetes config `~/.kube/config`.

Not certain this will work since you are running `halyard` and `kubectl` on different VM's.

```
# ~/.kube/config
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: http://my-kubernetes-url
  name: my-k8s-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: my-k8s-cluster
    namespace: default
  name: my-context
current-context: my-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```